# Google Analytics - Some weird URLs are being registered in behavior reports

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-firebase, google-analytics-filters

We made a google analytics account for one of our clients as part of the requirements.

Under **Reporting tab**, we have sections like **Behavior -> Site Content -> All pages**. In **All Pages** section we are able to see a table which contains all the urls which are viewed with respective **pageviews** , **unique pageviews** and other dimensions.

A normal page view looks like:"/pwsportal/faces/homePageNav/mktplan_adf.Ctrl_9_afrLoop_1234423".

Some how there are some weird page urls like :

[image]

I tried using **Exclude Filters** and couldn't eliminate these kind of urls.

From one on the blog i got to know that if any url contains any script tags it is a part of hacking technique called **cross site scripting**.

Finally i am here to find a solution to eliminate the these kind of existing urls and to prevent them from getting registered in future into google analytics.

Comment: It's not quite clear what you are asking - are you looking for an exclude filter that matches these urls ?

Comment: Yes, i would like to know the exclude filter pattern which matches these kind of urls and also i would like to know how these kind of urls get registered into google analytics. Can you please help me with this if you are aware of these kind of issue.@EikePierstorff